# Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@2b7374f8 returned null for URL

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, spring-boot

I am a beginner in JAVA.
I am trying to connect remote mySQL database to my Java code.

I am getting following error:

```
    2017-07-09 17:29:04.283 ERROR 38768 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000319: Could not get database metadata

java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@2b7374f8 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql:sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.home.Application.main(Application.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-07-09 17:29:04.284 ERROR 38768 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000299: Could not complete schema update

java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@2b7374f8 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql:sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.home.Application.main(Application.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my properties file:

```
    server.port=8090
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql:sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
spring.datasource.username=abc
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#hibernate config
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and my dependency in pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JDBC url is not in a format recognized by the MySQL Connector/J driver, so it is rejected by returning `null` as described in [`java.sql.Driver.connect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-):

> Attempts to make a database connection to the given URL. The driver
>   should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to
>   connect to the given URL. This will be common, as when the JDBC driver
>   manager is asked to connect to a given URL it passes the URL to each
>   loaded driver in turn.

As documented in the [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), the format of the URL for the MySQL Connector/J driver is:

> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]] »
> [?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
> ```

Your URL should at minimum be:

```
jdbc:mysql://sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
```

Comment: Thanks mark !! this have worked for me.
But now the problem is that this database is on godaddy.com and for accessing this database I always have to allow my IP address.
Is there any way so that I can connect to my database without giving specific permissions

Comment: @Girjesh That is something that you'd need to ask godaddy. In general it is a good security measure to not allow any random IP address on the internet to connect to a database. So needing to have your IP address whitelisted is normal (and from a security perspective: required). However, maybe godaddy has other options.

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource URL is wrong. It should be like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
```

You can read more about "Accessing data with MySQL" [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

Fix you connection first:

The correct one is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sg2plcpnl9557.produc.sin1.secure.net:3312/abc
```